# Python Unable to autolaunch a dbus-daemon without a $DISPLAY for X11 with autokey

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, dbus, autokey

Hi :) I use autokey on raspberry pi os.

I just want to use autokey script(`autokey-run -s autokeyscript`) with crontab (when reboot)

However, there are some errors.

I have already tried `export DISPLAY=:0`.
But the same error log appears.

the crontab log

```
  File "/usr/bin/autokey-run", line 34, in <module>
    bus = dbus.SessionBus()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/_dbus.py", line 211, in __new__
    mainloop=mainloop)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/_dbus.py", line 100, in __new__
    bus = BusConnection.__new__(subclass, bus_type, mainloop=mainloop)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 122, in __new__
    bus = cls._new_for_bus(address_or_type, mainloop=mainloop)
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NotSupported: Unable to autolaunch a dbus-daemon without a $DISPLAY for X11
display started
```

Autokey script

```
import time

image_path = '/dir/'
image_name = 'python file'
   
time.sleep(5)

# Open Terminal and run python script
# I know that I can run python script without autokey with using crontab, but I have to do this with this method.
keyboard.send_keys('<ctrl>+<alt>+t')
keyboard.send_keys(image_path)


keyboard.send_keys('<enter>')
time.sleep(3)

#keyboard.send_keys('<ctrl>+f')
keyboard.send_keys(image_name)
keyboard.send_keys('<enter>')
time.sleep(3)
keyboard.send_keys('<enter>')
```

Comment: what does your crontab command look like?

Comment: I use @reboot autokey-run -s autokeyscript